# How to find the limit of $\frac{1−\cos 5x}{x^2}$ as $x\to 0$?

Tags: limits

What is the right approach to calculate the Limit of $(1-\cos(5x))/x^2$ as $x \rightarrow 0$?

From [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+%281-cos+5x%29%2Fx%5E2+as+x+to+0), I found that:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1- \cos 5x}{x^2} = \frac{25}{2}.$$
How do I get that answer?

Comment: Please verify formatting didn't change your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use L’Hôpital’s rule, where $f(x) = 1-\cos 5x$ and $g(x)=x^2$, as
$$\lim_{x \to 0} (1-\cos 5x) = \lim_{x \to 0} x^2 = 0,$$
and $g'(x) = 2x \neq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

Then we get
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos 5x}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{5\sin 5x}{2x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{25 \cos 5x}{2} = \frac{25}{2},$$
where we apply L’Hôpital’s rule twice.

Comment: It should be $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1-\cos 5x}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{5\sin 5x}{\mathbf{2}x} $

Comment: @K.Rmth: of course, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{5\sin 5x}{2x} = \frac{5}{2}  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin 5x}{x} $$ is just the definition of the derivative of $\sin(5x)$ at $0$... So the second L'H use is circular logic....

Answer (score 10):

Using the equality
$$1-\cos2y=2\sin^2y$$
we have with $5x=2y$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos5x}{x^2}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{2\sin^2y}{\left(\frac{2y}{5}\right)^2}=\frac{25}{2}\lim_{y\to0}\left(\frac{\sin y}{y}\right)^2=\frac{25}{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos 5x}{x^2}\frac{1+\cos 5x}{1+\cos 5x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos^25x}{x^2}\frac{1}{1+\cos5x}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin5x}{5x}\right)^2\frac{25}{1+\cos5x}=\frac{25}{2}$$

Comment: +1 I just saw this question after [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863366/gre-limit-problem) was marked as a duplicate. This answer is almost identical to mine there.

Answer (score 4):

$\langle$ Begin of rant $\rangle$ It seems to be an effect of the choice made in some educational systems to inflate the importance of l'Hôpital's rule, that this (at best anecdotal) trick becomes the alpha and the omega of the approach by several MSEers of every question involving the local analysis of a real function. This happens at the expense of several other tools, often more important mathematically and at least as easy to use. As a consequence, let me humbly suggest that the extent of this monopole might be completely disproportionate, and even detrimental to the learning process of the field. $\langle$ End of rant $\rangle$

In the present case, a direct approach uses a quite rudimentary *limited expansion* of the cosine function at zero, namely, the fact that
$$
1-\cos(u)\sim\tfrac12u^2,\qquad u\to0.
$$
For $u=5x$, the fact that the limit asked about is $\frac{25}2$ becomes obvious.

To come back to the object of the rant, is it unreasonable to ask that anybody interested in mathematical analysis might know the equivalent used above (saying that the graph of cosine looks like a parabola around $0$), and that $\sin(u)\sim u$ and $\tan(u)\sim u$, and a few other similar expansions, say, $\mathrm e^u-1\sim u$ (fundamental) and $\sqrt{1+u}-1\sim\frac12u$ (each saying what is the slope of the tangent to a graph at $0$), rather than the intricacies of a black box called l'Hôpital's rule (whose requirements, by the way, are almost never checked)? Honestly, I do not think so.

Comment: I think the inflation in the perception of importance of l'Hôpital's rule is mostly caused by its power(at least in solving lots of popular problems) rather than the choice of educational system. When I was in high school at some time we were banned(!) to use the rule, but everybody was secretly using it to check his answer!

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with the first and the last paragraph. I also concur that the solution of the problem in between is the best and easiest solution of this problem.

Comment: @hhsaffar Really? Please test the "power" of l'H on the limit of $(1-\cos(5x)+\sin(17x)^3-\mathrm e^{-42/x^2})/(x^2+\sqrt[3]{x^7+x^9})$ when $x\to0$.

Comment: @Did I have nothing against knowing the limited expansions, however, putting the instance you proposed aside, with l'H you have to memorize much less, you can know nothing about expansions and series, a topic that is not frequently taught in high schools, and yet you can answer almost all high school level\early college questions.It is powerful because it lets you to solve lots of problems without knowing much.

Comment: In your last edit, you introduced an orthographic Gallicism (fondamental).

Comment: @DanielFischer Oops, thanks.

Comment: @Did : not everyone will be able or willing to memorize the power series expansions of all the functions you think are important.  What about $\tan^{-1}$?  $\ln$?  Where do you draw the line?  L'Hopital's Rule is easy to remember and use (in typical problems, there are no "intricacies").  In addition, few students know what "little-o" notation means.  It, as well as "big-O" notation, are not part of most calculus sequences.  Whether they should be is a separate question.  I do think many students overuse it, and attempt to use it for everything, before trying a little algebra and common sense.

Comment: Actually, an interesting question would be to determine when the place of l'Hôpital's rule began to be so preeminent in certain curricula, which other, previous, expertises it replaced, and how the move was justified (if it was perceived) at the time by its proponents.

Comment: However, I think you missed the big picture. Some students in high school know nothing about Maclaurin series, and therefore the use of the limited expansions isn't always advisable. These limits are mainly met in high school.

Comment: honestly, to understand that $$\sin x \sim x$$,  and that $$x^2 + x \sim x$$ (x -> 0) is trivial, it does not involve mac Laurin, and it does simplify enourmously the calculations.. I would teach that in high school

Comment: @Chris'ssis Thanks for your reaction. Note that Maclaurin series are not even mentioned in my post and that they are off-topic. I rephrased, to emphasize that only some basic equivalents are at stake here, that is, knowing what the graphs of some of the most common functions *look like* around zero.

Comment: @StefanSmith Thanks for your reaction. I fail to recognize the content of my post in the dilemnas you say. Little-o and big-O are quite inessential here (btw, I rephrased my remark in terms of simple equivalents). List of functions: already the ones mentioned in the post, plus $1/(1-x)$ and the logarithm, would allow to go a long way. Importantly, you do not mention that many of these equivalents are *intimately related*. To learn by heart a huge list of expansions would be stupid (and it is not the way things are presented in the curricula I know which escape l'H's obsession). Rather, .../...

Comment: .../... what happens is that to be at ease with a few of these expansions/equivalents allows to reinforce one's understanding of the subject. For example, the expansions of the exponential, the sine and the cosine are really one result, *plus the relations between these functions*. Knowing the former makes one aware of the latter, thus I strongly object to your *memorize*. Precisely, l'H's rule has morphed into a recipe students try to *memorize* (more or less accurately), which effectively prevents them to *think*, that is, to do some actual maths, or, in your words, .../...

Comment: .../... to rely on "a little algebra and common sense". I could not agree more with this formulation.

Answer (score 2):

Use L'Hopital's Rule:

Since the limit evaluates to the form $\frac 00$ as is, we can take the derivative of the numerator and denominator, and then evaluate the limit as $x\to 0$; if it still evaluates to the form $\frac 00$, take the derivative of the numerator and denominator *again*, and evaluate the resulting limit as $x\to 0$. Etc: Here, we apply L'H twice:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos 5x}{x^2} \quad \overset{L'H}{=} \quad \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{5\sin 5x}{2x}\quad \overset{L'H}{=}\quad \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{25 \cos 5x}{2} \quad = \quad\frac{25}{2}$$

Comment: It should be $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1-\cos 5x}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{5\sin 5x}{\mathbf{2}x} $

Answer (score 2):

$\cos(2\alpha) = 1-2\sin ^2 \alpha$

Therefore

$\frac{1-\cos (5x)}{x^2}=\frac{2 \sin ^2 \left( \frac{5x}{2}\right)}{x^2} = \frac{25}{2} \left( \frac{\sin \frac{5}{2}x}{\frac{5}{2}x} \right)^2 \rightarrow \frac{25}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

There is a really easy way of doing this, take derivatives. Namely:
$$ \partial_{5} \frac{1- Cos(5x)}{x^{2}} =\frac{xSin(5x)}{x^{2}}=\frac{Sin(5x)}{x} \to 5$$ 
Now, since we took a derivative w.r.t 5, we must take the integral with respect to 5:
$$\int 5 \mathrm{d}5=\frac{5^2}{2}=25/2$$

Answer (score 0):

L'Hospital's Rule, twice. You will have a $25cos5x$ in the num, and a 2 in the denom, supporting your answer