# Solving limits without using L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{b(1-\sin x) }{(\pi-2x)^2}$$

I had been solving questions like these using L'Hôpital's rule since weeks. But today, a day before the examination, I got to know that its usage has been 'banned', since we were never officially taught L'Hôpital's rule.

Now I am at a loss how to solve questions I breezed through previously. While it is not possible to learn in 18 hours methods that would cover all kinds of problems, I am hoping I can pick up enough of them to salvage the examination tomorrow.

It has been hinted to me that the above could be solved using trigonometric techniques, but I'm at a loss as to how.

Answer (score 6):

That's a good thing L'Hospital's rule has been banned. If it is not well applied, it can lead to errors, and when it works, using Taylor's formula at order $1$ is logically equivalent. Very often, using equivalents is the shortest way to compute a limit.

That said, use substitution: set $x=\dfrac\pi2-h$; $h\to 0$ if $x\to\dfrac\pi2$. Then
$$\frac{b(1-\sin x)}{(\pi-2x)^2}=\frac{b(1-\cos h)}{4h^2}$$
Now it is a standard limit that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1-\cos h}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1-\cos^2 h}{h^2(1+\cos h)}=\lim_{h\to 0}\Bigl(\frac{\sin h}h\Bigr)^2\frac1{(1+\cos h)}=\frac12.$$
Thus the limit in question is equal to $\color{red}{\dfrac b8}.$

Comment: Could you elaborate on how L'Hopital's rule could lead to errors? I'd like to avoid making them. And thank you for the answer.

Comment: One of the commonest errors  is to apply the rule repeatedly to solve an indetermination and forget it is valid only in case of indetermination, going one step too far.  (a caricature would be to obtain at some step $\frac x1$, proceed to $\frac  10$ and conclude to an infinite limit!)

Comment: But by that logic the incorrect application of any theorem can lead to errors, so all theorems must be avoided.

Comment: The difference is it is not a real theorem: as I said, it is equivalent to Taylor at order $1$. With Taylor, you won't have the problem. So why use  an error-prone rule  that can be replaced with a more general formula, that does not have the same pitfall? I don't ay it *never* must be used, but very often students try to compute improbable derivatives just to apply their beloved L'Hospital's rule…

Comment: A letter other than $h$ might be better for substitutions involving $\sin$, $\cos$, $\tan$...

Comment: @Benjamin Dickman: Why that?

Comment: Because e.g. $\sin h$ looks a bit like $\sinh$ (hyperbolic sine); same for cosh, tanh...

Comment: I don't think it is that confusing: it's italic, there is a lonely $h^2$ in the denominator, and it is a traditional notation for small increments of the variable. What do you think of $\ln n$ then?

Comment: Taylor at order 1 is simply the definition of derivative. L'Hospital theorem is much more than that...

Comment: Of course it's an extension to indeterminate forms  other than $0/0$ and other special cases, but ultimately, it is really nothing more. In any case I've never seen a limit which could not be solved with Taylors formula, but was solved with L'Hospital.

Comment: In which possible sense is L'Hospitals's rule "not a real theorem"?

Comment: @RR "But by that logic the incorrect application of any theorem can lead to errors, so all theorems must be avoided." This is the theory, magnificent and flawless as every piece of theory. Now, in the real world, some theorems are useful, either because they allow to prove results that others don't, or because they are taught to, and routinely applied by, students in a more of less correct way. L'Hôpital's rule fails spectacularly on both counts. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/749184/ http://math.stackexchange.com/a/567301/ http://math.stackexchange.com/q/857072/

Comment: @HenningMakholm "In which possible sense is L'Hospitals's rule "not a real theorem"?" The OP explains what they mean in the very next sentence: L'Hôpital's rule *is equivalent to Taylor at order $1$*. (Note: L'Hospital or L'Hôpital but not L'Hospitals.)

Comment: @RR *because they allow to prove results that others don't... Please read: because they provide simpler proofs or they allow to prove results that others don't...

Comment: @Did: So being equivalent to a special case of a theorem can make the rule a non-theorem? That sounds mindbogglingly inconsistent to me In the logic I have learned, being implied by something you already know is a theorem is _one of the most basic and fundamental ways you establish that something IS a real theorem_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Please stop the rhetoric and if you want to be exact, please at least do not distort what the OP said. OP did not say this was a non-theorem but "not a real theorem". This is an admittedly vague statement but if one honestly ponders what the OP could mean by it, one soon arrives at *the meaning I explained in my comment*. To repeat: L'Hôpital's rule is a theorem, and this theorem happens to be implied by (a weak form of) another theorem called Taylor's formula. Hence the "not a real theorem". Example: "No multiple of 8 is prime" is "not a real theorem" because you-know-what.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{b(1-\sin x)}{(\pi-2x)^2}&=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{b(1-\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2}))}{(\pi -2x)^2}\\\\&=\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{b\sin^2(x-\frac{\pi}{2})}{4(x-\frac{\pi}{2})^2(1+\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2}))}\\\\&=\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{b}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2})}\cdot\left(\frac{\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{2})}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)^2\\\\&=\frac{b}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{1+1}\cdot 1^2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use trigonometry identities:

$$\sin(x)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\\\sin\frac{t}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos t)}$$

Specifically, set $t=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ then you want:

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{b(1-\cos t)}{4t^2}$$

Then use the trig identities above, replacing $1-\cos t$.

Answer (score 1):

If $b = 0$, then there is nothing to work out; let $b \neq 0$. But
$$
\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{b(1 - \sin x)}{(\pi - 2x)^{2}} = b\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1 - \sin (h + \pi/2)}{4h^{2}} = b\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1 - \sin h \cos (\pi /2) - \cos h \sin (\pi/2)}{4h^{2}}\\ = b\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos h}{4h^{2}} = b\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\frac{h^{2}}{2} + o(h^{2})}{4h^{2}} = \frac{b}{8}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

we get $$\frac{(1-\sin(x))(1+\sin(x))}{(1+\sin(x))(\pi-2x)^2}$$ with $t=\pi-2x$ we get $$\frac{(\sin(t/2))^2}{4(\frac{t}{2})^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I've always hated limits that don't approach zero, so my first step is to make the limit approach zero by expressing everything in terms of $x-\frac{\pi}{2}$, then make the subsitution $\theta = x - \frac{\pi}{2}$.

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{b(1-\sin x)}{(\pi-2x)^2}&=&\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{b(1-\sin ((x-\frac{\pi}{2})+\frac{\pi}{2}))}{(\pi-2((x-\frac{\pi}{2})+\frac{\pi}{2}))^2}\\
&=&\displaystyle\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{b(1-\sin (\theta+\frac{\pi}{2}))}{(\pi-2(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2}))^2}\\
&=&\displaystyle\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{b(1-\sin (\theta+\frac{\pi}{2}))}{4\theta^2}\\
\end{array}$$

Can you take it from here?

**Hint:** $\sin (A+B)=\sin A \cos B + \cos A \ sin B$